# Django JOIN with column renaming to queryset

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to build my django queryset with a join, and a colum-renaming. Unfortunately two fields of my have the same name, so the queryset does not return the values, as I expected it.

my models are like that:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
     text = models.CharField('Text', max_length=200, unique=True)

class UserQuestionnaire(models.Model):
     creation = models.DateField('creation date')

class UserChoice(models.Model):
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
     questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(UserQuestionnaire)
     text = models.CharField('Text', max_length=200)  # same field name
     votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My desired query for the output is like:
    select * from polls_userchoice inner join polls_question;

which returns a table like that:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-------+----+-------+
| id | question_id | questionnaire_id | text | votes | id | text  |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-------+----+-------+
|  1 |           1 |                3 | 2    |     0 |  1 | text1 |
|  2 |           4 |                3 | 6    |     0 |  2 | text2 |
|  3 |           3 |                3 | 6    |     0 |  3 | text3 |
```

My django queryset with

```py
user_choice_list = UserChoice.objects.filter(
    questionnaire=user_questionnaire.id).select_related('question')
```

returns only a dictionnary like this

```py
[{'questionnaire_id': 3L, 'votes': 0L, 'text': u'2', u'id': 1L, 'question_id': 1L},
 {'questionnaire_id': 3L, 'votes': 0L, 'text': u'6', u'id': 2L, 'question_id': 4L},
 {'questionnaire_id': 3L, 'votes': 0L, 'text': u'6', u'id': 3L, 'question_id': 3L}]
```

So my question is, is it possible to rename the second 'text' column of the question model during the query so I can access it from the queryset methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)() instead of select_related(). Such as

```
user_choice_list = (UserChoice.objects
    .filter(questionnaire=user_questionnaire.id)
    .values(
        'id' , 
        'question_id' , 
        'questionnaire_id', 
        'question__text', 
        'votes', 
        'text'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately django could not resolve 'question_text' into a field. It has to be renamed somehow. (I'm using django 1.6, if this may help)

Comment: sorry its should be question__text, I have edited it in my answer.

Comment: The double underscore did the trick. Thank you, for your quick answer.

Comment: Always you have to access related data using double underscores.